# Grup graphics lag

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, bootloader, thinkpad

I've just set up Ubuntu 13.10 on a new laptop. It's a thinkpad T540p and grub is having some really strange problems.

After the bios flash screen grup starts to load. The screen goes black and the purple "ubuntu" colour starts "rolling" up from the bottom. Then the white text slowly builds up. After the text has fully loaded, the operating system can be chosen, this is very laggy, too.

A friend recommended changing the resolution of grub. The display has a resolution of 2800x1600 and we suspected that grub was having problems with this resolution but even setting it as low as 800*640 didn't improve the performance.